# Remove period after author (year) generated by \usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}?

Tags: biblatex, biber, punctuation, authoryear

My bib file:

```
@book{tgt,
  title = {The Great Title},
  author = {Jane Doe},
  year = {2022},
  publisher = {Macmillan},
  address = {Paris},
}
```

My LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}
\begin{document}

A proof can be found at \textcite{tgt}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The reference list looks like this:

> Doe, Jane (2022). *The Great Title.* Paris: Macmillan.

How can I remove the period after author (year) so that the reference list looks like this:

> Doe, Jane (2022) *The Great Title.* Paris: Macmillan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant punctuation is controlled by `nametitledelim`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
A proof can be found at \textcite{sigfridsson}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998) “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”]